# raspbian on RPi4: kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000007

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, kernel, raspbian-buster

For an unknown reason, my RPi4 (latest version of Raspbian) stopped last night during an unattended-upgrade. The most recent traces I found in /var/log are (sorry, in French):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail /media/pi/ROOT/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
2020-04-13 04:08:04,863 INFO Initial whitelist:
2020-04-13 04:08:04,864 INFO Démarrage du script de mise à niveau automatique
2020-04-13 04:08:04,864 INFO Les origines permises sont: o=Debian,n=buster, o=deb.sury.org,n=buster, o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=buster, o=Raspbian,n=stretch,l=Raspbian, origin=Debian,codename=buster-updates, origin=Debian,codename=buster-proposed-updates, origin=Debian,codename=buster,label=Debian, origin=Debian,codename=buster,label=Debian-Security
2020-04-13 06:47:48,301 INFO Checking if system is running on battery is skipped. Please install powermgmt-base package to check power status and skip installing updates when the system is running on battery.
2020-04-13 06:47:48,345 INFO Initial blacklist :
2020-04-13 06:47:48,346 INFO Initial whitelist:
2020-04-13 06:47:48,347 INFO Démarrage du script de mise à niveau automatique
2020-04-13 06:47:48,348 INFO Les origines permises sont: o=Debian,n=buster, o=deb.sury.org,n=buster, o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=buster, o=Raspbian,n=stretch,l=Raspbian, origin=
Debian,codename=buster-updates, origin=Debian,codename=buster-proposed-updates, origin=Debian,codename=buster,label=Debian, origin=Debian,codename=buster,label=Debian-Security
2020-04-13 06:48:06,090 INFO Paquets mis à niveau: fonts-opensymbol libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-dri
vers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffic
e-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer python3-uno rpi-eeprom rpi-eeprom-images uno-libs3 ure
2020-04-13 06:48:06,091 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
```

or this one:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail /media/pi/ROOT/var/log/dpkg.log
2020-04-13 06:48:26 status half-configured libreoffice-draw:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5
2020-04-13 06:48:26 status unpacked libreoffice-draw:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5
2020-04-13 06:48:26 status half-installed libreoffice-draw:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5
2020-04-13 06:48:26 status unpacked libreoffice-draw:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5+rpt1
2020-04-13 06:48:27 upgrade python3-uno:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5+rpt1
2020-04-13 06:48:27 status half-configured python3-uno:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5
2020-04-13 06:48:27 status unpacked python3-uno:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5
2020-04-13 06:48:27 status half-installed python3-uno:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5
2020-04-13 06:48:27 status unpacked python3-uno:armhf 1:6.1.5-3+rpi1+deb10u5+rpt1
```

And other ones at 06:48, all related to the upgrade. So no obvious issue...

Unfortunately, when I try to restart the Pi, I get:

```
kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000007
```

I am unable to see the "real" message before this one as it scrolls very fast and I can't find any log.

My configuration is to boot on a hard disk (configured in cmdline.txt) so I changed it back to boot on the SD Card and there, everyting is working fine ==> the SD Card itself has no problem...

In this configuration, the hard disk is mounted automatically on /media/pi/ROOT, I can read it without any problem, and I checked it with fsck.ext4 and was told it is clean.

```
$ sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ROOT: clean, 418057/1835008 files, 3114608/7325696 blocks
```

So I'm a bit stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved
It works again and the problem was ... in the USB-SATA cable between the Pi and the disk.

After retrying again, I realized that I couldn't access the disk at all anymore with a message explicitly speaking about the cable at boot time.

I used a different external disk case that I had on hand and miracle!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.